# Ran privazer on my SSD and now I can't login

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, login, login-screen

So after it ran, it restarted my computer. Once I get to the login screen it says 'Other User' Where my account would usually be. I can't login because I used a pin code to login to my computer. I tried using the e-mail as the username and the e-mail password to login but no luck. The power options don't show up either so I have to hold down the power button on my case to shutdown the computer. Any help? I'm currently creating a Windows Media Tool on my USB to refresh my computer if it comes to it.

I have tried:

- Shift + F8 to get into safe mode
- Also just F8
- Booting into UEFI BIOS to see if I can do anything through there - I
  can choose what to boot into.

EDIT: Privazer is a tool that cleans up your computer. Link here: http://privazer.com/

**Fixed by resetting computer. I got to that point by turning off the computer while Windows was loading. This is not safe but it did the job.**

Comment: You got to tell us what "privazer" is, some information on it, sounds like snake oil that corrupted your installation

Comment: Ok, I edited OP. @Ramhound

Comment: First of all, a welcome to Super User!  I have a couple of friendly pieces of advice to pass along. As Ramhound already implied, programs like "Privazer" are often rather shady and unreliable, and unfortunately you witnessed that first-hand. In the future, I would avoid applications and services like those... they will typically do more harm than good. Always, we don't really put *"SOLVED"* in our questions' titles. Instead, we submit an answer (or in this case, our own answer) and officially mark it as the accepted solution. You will also need to wait through the 48-hour grace period.

Comment: We're happy you've fixed the issue and learned some things while doing it. In order to help others who have the same problem, do as @Run5k suggests and enter your solution as an Answer. After 48 hours you'll be able to mark your own answer as THE answer.

Comment: Fixed by resetting computer. I got to that point by turning off the computer while Windows was loading. This is not safe but it did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by resetting computer. I got to that point by turning off the computer while Windows was loading. This is not safe but it did the job.